# Getting textbox values into array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to get value from textbox and save as array. My code uses words combined with numbers . I'm trying to group these gererated words and place it (each word) into an array field . 
My code doesn't seperate the words , it just put all the words in one array field .

**Code :**

```
  function a()
{
var text = prompt("Please enter your username"); 
var i;
var j ;
j = prompt("Please enter number of usersname ") ;
var text1 = "";

for(i = 1; i < j ; i++)
{
    text1+= text + i + " " ;
}
document.getElementById("txtFloodMsg").value = text1; // putting values in textbox 
}



function Nickname() {


var array =[];
var Guser;
Guser = document.getElementById("txtFloodMsg").value; //taking values from the textbox
array =  Guser.split(' '); // split it (here is the problem i guess)
var length = array.length;
var randome = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
var index = array.indexOf(randome);
document.getElementById("nick").value = randome;

    var r = confirm("Is It Okay To Continue ?");
    if ( r == true )
     {
        if(index>-1 && length > -1)
        {
           array.splice(index,1);
           document.getElementById("nick").value = randome;
           pass();
           checked();
        }
    else if( r != true )  
        {  
          randome = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
          document.getElementById("nick").value = randome;
          var s = confirm("Is It Okay To Continue ?");
          while ( s != true ) 
              {
               randome = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
               document.getElementById("nick").value = randome;
               s = confirm("Is It Okay To Continue ?");

                }

          pass();
          checked(); 
          }


      }


}
```

Please help , Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myArray = [];
// ..

for(i = 1; i < j ; i++)
{
    myArray.push(text);
}

// ..
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nek2Lmph/1

Comment: could you be more specific ?!

Comment: If you could be more specific **what** words you want to have in an array :)

Comment: it would be something like this (fish0r1 fish0r2 fish0r3 fish0r4 fish0r5 fish0r6 fish0r7 fish0r8 fish0r9 fish0r10 fish0r11) and so on ( it's generated in the function a() @devqon

Comment: Are those the `randome` variables? Can you throw it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: yeah it's a random variables , depends on  what i want .. excuse me what is a jsfiddle ?! @devqon

Comment: Please specify your intentions and which variables you want in the array (where in your code)

Comment: function a() generate usernames combined with number as the user want so it asks you what is the username , then how much usernames you want .. and create a for loop which generate the final users (ex entered name devqon  quantity 3 => it return  devqon1 devqon2 devqon3 into a textbox cold textFloodMsg . 
what i'm trying to do is to get this generated values from the textFloodMsg and put each user in one array cell . the code i wrote is not working ...

Comment: The answer is correct, he just doesn't know how to use it. @fish0r checkout this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nek2Lmph/1/

Comment: @devqon , yeah this is working thank you man , sorry i've not noticed your recent comment .. Thank you :) :)